# sending multiple comma separator value to a function

Tags: javascript

I want to send multiple comma separator value to a function through javascript. The function get the first value only. Please help me to solve this.

```
onclick='add_values(" + items + ");return false;'
```

Items mean '98,97,96,95..'

```
function add_values(items) {
     try {
       alert(plans); // 98 only
       ...
}
```

But the function get only the first Value. 98.

Comment: read up on javascript split or substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method can be used to get an array from your comma separated string:

```
function add_values(items)
{
    var list = items.split(",");

    console.log( list[0] ); // 98
    console.log( list[1] ); // 97
    console.log( list[2] ); // 96
    console.log( list[3] ); // 95
}
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> Splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

You also need to use quotes when passing a string value to a function in that way:

```
onclick='add_values(\'" + items + "\');return false;'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not set inline event handler attribute strings by javascript. That technique is outdated for over a decade now, there are [better event registration models](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html).

If you really had to, it should look like this:

```
htmlstr = "<div onclick='add_values(" + JSON.stringify(items) + ");return false;'>…</div>";
```